# cursor index out of bounds “index 0 requested: with size 0”

Tags: android, android-cursor

I am getting `cursor index out of bounds` ***"index 0 requested: with size 0"*** error when I search for sms in inbox.I have written the code below:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{

               String msgData = "";
               for(int idx=0;idx<cursor.getColumnCount();idx++)
               {
                   msgData += " " + cursor.getColumnName(idx) + ":" + cursor.getString(idx);
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msgData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    });  
 }
```

Comment: Which line causes the error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that your query returns results before calling any methods on the Cursor. You can do this by checking that `cursor.getCount() > 0`.

Comment: sms are present in the simulator inbox still gives exception

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return value of `cursor.moveToFirst()` or simply check `cursor.getCount()`

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
       if ( cursor.getCount() > 0 )
          for(int i=0;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
          {
              cursor.moveToPosition(i);

           String msgData = "";
           for(int idx=0;idx<cursor.getColumnCount();idx++)
           {
               msgData += " " + cursor.getColumnName(idx) + ":" + cursor.getString(idx);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msgData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }

        }else
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No message was found in device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check your cursor.moveToNext() as follows :

```
if(cursor.moveToNext())
{
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
    {
         //do your job.
         cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

The problem arouse because you are **using do while loop** and **not even checking** that the **cursor is having any row or not**.